# Child update parent state not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to have a navBar update the main component.

```
class NavBar extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  clickHandler(handlerCode){
    this.props.handleClick(handlerCode);
  }

  render(){
    var self = this;
    var options = this.props.options;
    var listItems = options.map(function(data, index){
      return (<li key={'navBar.' + index} onClick={() => self.clickHandler(data.handlerCode)}>{data.name}</li>);
      });
    return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
  }
}

class Student extends Component {
  //This class will create the entire student interface
  //It will retrieve data from the server
  //However, there will be two subclass (StudentNavBar and StudentView)
  //That will render the data necessary to do this


  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentView: 'simplified',
      simplifiedViewData: {
        monday: "Study Hall",
        tuesday: "Computer Science Club",
        wednesday: "Science Enrichment",
        thursday: "Hawkeye",
        friday: "Hurtado Food Pantry",
      },
      navBar : [
        {name: "Sign Up", handlerCode: "signup" ,},
        {name: "Quick", handlerCode: "simplifiedView", },
        {name: "Detailed" , handlerCode: "detailedView" ,},
        {name: "Logout" , handlerCode:"logout"},
      ],
    }
    this.state.children = <StudentView viewData={this.state.simplifiedViewData} view={'none'} />; //will probably default to simplified, but for testign
  }

  render(){
    var self = this;
    return (<div><NavBar handleClick={self.handleClick} options={this.state.navBar} />{this.state.children}</div>);
  }

  handleClick(input){
    if(input == 'simplifiedView'){
      console.log(this);
      this.state.children = <StudentView viewData={this.state.simplifiedViewData} view={'simplifiedView'} />;
    }
  }
}
```

However, when ever the handleClick() event is called from the NavBar class, this is treated as the NavBar component and not the StudentView. As the child component does not have a state (should I change that?), it throws an error. How would I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the event handler to the component.

In your constructor:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

And your `render` function:

```
render(){
    return (<div><NavBar handleClick={this.handleClick} options={this.state.navBar} />{this.state.children}</div>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this